# How to set up Spark cluster on laptop?

Tags: apache-spark

I am completely new at Spark and try to run a tutorial [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html), which counts the number of lines containing 'a' and 'b' in a text file in the local file system.

I am running it with `SparkContext` with `master = "local"`, i.e. `Spark` is running in the same JVM. Now I would like to try it in "cluster mode".

So I would like to run a Spark cluster of a cluster manager and two worker nodes locally on my Mac laptop. What is the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: I haven't done something like that before but this looks like it could work : https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/14/setup-a-apache-spark-cluster-in-your-single-standalone-machine/

Comment: The documentation itself tells you some pretty easy steps to follow to spin up a simple cluster: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation about [Spark Standalone Mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html):

> ```
> ./sbin/start-master.sh
>
> ./sbin/start-slave.sh <master-spark-URL>
> ```

In other words, you should start the standalone Master first (using `./sbin/start-master.sh`) followed by starting one or more standalone Workers (using `./sbin/start-slave.sh`).

Quoting the docs again:

> Once you have started a worker, look at the master's web UI (http://localhost:8080 by default)

You're done. *Congrats!*

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to learn various ways to use `SPARK` I would suggest you to download the `CLOUDERA` quick start VM's which will give a simple cluster setup.

All you need to do is download the `quick start` VM and play around with the settings accordingly.

The `quick start` VM can be found here

Reference:[Cloudera VM](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html)